# How to rename pandas dataframe column with another dataframe?

Tags: pandas

I really don't understand what I'm doing. I have two data frames. One has a list of column labels and another has a bunch of data. I want to just label the columns in my data with my column labels.

My Code:

```
airportLabels = pd.read_csv('airportsLabels.csv', header= None)

airportData = pd.read_table('airports.dat', sep=",", header = None)
df = DataFrame(airportData, columns = airportLabels)
```

When I do this, all the data turns into "NaN" and there is only one column anymore. I am really confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need add parameter `nrows` to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), if you need read only columns, remove `header= None`, because first row of `csv` is column names and then use parameter `names` in [`read_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_table.html) with `columns` from `DataFrame` `airportLabels` :

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""col1,col2,col3
1,5,4
7,8,5"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
airportLabels = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), nrows=0)
print airportLabels
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [col1, col2, col3]
Index: []

temp=u"""
a,d,f
e,r,t"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_table(io.StringIO(temp), sep=",", header = None, names=airportLabels.columns)
print df
  col1 col2 col3
0    a    d    f
1    e    r    t
```

Comment: Thank you, but that didn't seem to work. The data is there now (no more NaNs), but the column labels are now "0,1,2...etc)

Comment: Please give me time, I test it.

Comment: Thank you so much! Removing the "headers=none" from the labels file seemed to fix it.